# How to get value from Dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two `DropDownList` which are related to each other by a foreign key.
Category and Subcategory(with `categoryid` as foreign key).
I am retrieving **Categories** from database and filling them up as:
**DB CLASS**

```
public class DB
 {
     public static List<SelectListItem> Categories {
              get{
                   List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem {
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "Category1" , Value = "categoryId1"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "Category2" , Value = "categoryId2"}
                 };
        return list;
     }
    public static List<SelectListItem> SubcategoryWithCategoryId(int categoryId)
    {...}
 }
```

Now i can fill Subcategory dropdown with a method which expects categoryId as input:
**View**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Category", DB.Categories, "Select Category", new { style = "width:80px" })

 @Html.DropDownList("Subcategory", DB.SubcategoryWithCategoryId(categoryId), "Select Subcategory", new { style = "width:80px" })
```

I am a beginner in **ASP.NET MVC** and i am using **ADO.NET** to access the database.
How can i now get the Selected Item's Value Field so i can fit it into my `DB.SubcategoryWithCategoryId(categoryId)` to retrieve subcategories mapped across the selected category?

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: add your code about controller and your view too

Comment: @HienNguyen Okay i have edited my question..

Comment: In which method you would like to do your update operation based on your selected value against you database, can you show it?

Comment: @SalahAkbari For now i just want when i select value in categories dropdown the subcategories dropdown gets filled.

Comment: What happens if you change `@Html.DropDownList("Category"` to `@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId"`? They need to be same in order Model Binder works as expected,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need handle onchange of dropdown as

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Category", DB.Categories, "Select Category", new { style = "width:80px", 
onchange = "location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Controller", new { category= "yourcategory"})'" })
```

And add category as paramter of index action

```
public ActionResult Index(string category)
```